# Correct syntax for Google Universal Analytics event tracking

Tags: object, events, analytics, tracking, universal

From Google's [guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) for event tracking, you can send an object with extra options for your event, like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {'nonInteraction': 1});
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {'page': '/my-new-page'});
```

Then they say you can pass a field object to the "ga" function, like this:

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',          // Required.
  'eventCategory': 'button',   // Required.
  'eventAction': 'click',      // Required.
  'eventLabel': 'nav buttons',
  'eventValue': 4
});
```

or

```
ga('send', 'event', {
  'eventCategory': 'Category',
  'eventAction': 'Action',
  'eventValue': 55
});
```

But how can I add extra options to this second syntax? How can I add **{'nonInteraction': 1}** for example?

---

Can I add it like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', {
  'eventCategory': 'Category',
  'eventAction': 'Action',
  'eventValue': 55
}, {'nonInteraction': 1});
```

Or like this?

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',          
  'eventCategory': 'button',  
  'eventAction': 'click',      
  'eventLabel': 'nav buttons',
  'eventValue': 4,
  'nonInteraction': 1
});
```

Comment: Just curiosity, but what programming language are you using there?

Comment: @JuanRocamonde: JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

They don't explain that very well, the correct way would be this:

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',          
  'eventCategory': 'button',  
  'eventAction': 'click',      
  'eventLabel': 'nav buttons',
  'eventValue': 4,
  'nonInteraction': 1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be the latter, but you could also try it out and verify by checking in real time reports or by copying the code and pasting it into the console and seeing if the hits show up in the developer tools network tab.